# xslt standardize nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xslt, nosql, marklogic

I work on a generic XSL to standardize different nested JSON.
My sample JSONs

/soccer2.json

```
{
"position": "main", 
"others": "spiss;sweeper", 
"player": 
  {
    "midtbane": [
      "offensiv-midtbane", 
      "defensiv-midtbane"
    ]
  }
}
```

/soccer1.json

```
{
 "position": "main", 
 "others": [
    {
        "wing": "høyreving;venstreving", 
        "fullback": [
              "venstreback", 
              "høyreback"
        ]
    }
  ], 
  "player": [
        {
          "left": "venstre-midtbane", 
          "center": "høyre-midtbane", 
          "right": "sentral-midtbane"
        }
    ]   
  }
```

My xsl

```
const myXsl =
  fn.head(xdmp.unquote(
`
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">  
  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <sport>
            <xsl:if test="exists(position)">
                <positionType>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="position"/>
                </positionType>
            </xsl:if> 
            
        <!--    <xsl:if test="exists(others)">
                <otherPosition>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="others"/>
                </otherPosition>
            </xsl:if>   
-->
 
            <xsl:if test="exists(player)">
                <playerPosition>
                   <xsl:for-each select="player/child::node()">
                     <xsl:element name="{name()}">  
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                     </xsl:element>  
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </playerPosition>
            </xsl:if>            
        </sport>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:transform>
`));
const doc = cts.doc('/soccer2.json')
xdmp.xsltEval(myXsl, doc)
```

Unexpected output:

```
/soccer2.json
<sport>
  <positionType>main</positionType>
  <otherPosition>spiss;sweeper</otherPosition>
  <playerPosition>
    <midtbane>["offensiv-midtbane", "defensiv-midtbane"]</midtbane>
  </playerPosition>
</sport>
```

Expected output:

```
/soccer2.json
<sport>
  <positionType>main</positionType>
  <otherPosition>spiss;sweeper</otherPosition>
  <playerPosition>
    <midtbane>offensiv-midtbane</midtbane>
    <midtbane>defensiv-midtbane</midtbane>
  </playerPosition>
</sport>
```

Do I expect this work in XSLT?

Comment: Something is missing from your description. The input to XSLT is XML, not JSON. An XSLT 3.0 processor can *read* JSON - but your stylesheet says  `version="2.0"` and includes no attempt to parse JSON. Apparently you have a preliminary stage that converts JSON to XML before feeding it to the XSL transformation. We need to see that XML. Try using a stylesheet with only the [identity transform template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) to get it.

Comment: No worry, we thank everyone for the help! (We do read every response and comment in great details. And we don’t miss a thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MarkLogic XSLT implementation, you should be looking at:

```
const implFlattenJToX=
  fn.head(xdmp.unquote(
`
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"
    xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml" exclude-result-prefixes="xdmp" version="2.0">
        
    <xsl:template name="sport">        
        <xsl:variable name="v_position" select="position"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v_others" select="others"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v_player" select="player"/>        
        <sport>
            <xsl:if test="exists(position)">
                <positionType>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="position"/>
                </positionType>
            </xsl:if> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="exists($v_others/node())">                     
                    <otherPosition>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$v_others">
                            <xsl:call-template name="flattenJson"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </otherPosition>  
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="exists($v_others)">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$v_others" mode="flatNode">
                            <xsl:with-param name="eName" select="'otherPosition'"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>   
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>             
            <xsl:if test="exists($v_player)">
                <playerPosition>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/player">
                        <xsl:call-template name="flattenJson"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </playerPosition>
            </xsl:if>      
        </sport>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="flattenJson">
        <xsl:for-each select="*"> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="array-node()|object-node()">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./node()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="xdmp:from-json(.)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{(name(.))}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template> 
    
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="flatNode">
        <xsl:param name="eName"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$eName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>     
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="sport"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:transform>

`));
```

> Output:

```
<sport>
    <positionType>main</positionType>
    <otherPosition>
        <wing>høyreving;venstreving</wing>
        <fullback>venstreback</fullback>
        <fullback>høyreback</fullback>
    </otherPosition>
    <playerPosition>
        <left>venstre-midtbane</left>
        <center>høyre-midtbane</center>
        <right>sentral-midtbane</right>
    </playerPosition>
</sport>

<sport>
    <positionType>main</positionType>
    <otherPosition>spiss;sweeper</otherPosition>
    <playerPosition>
        <midtbane>offensiv-midtbane</midtbane>
        <midtbane>defensiv-midtbane</midtbane>
    </playerPosition>
</sport>
```

> Side note: 1) MarkLogic built-in function `json:transform-from-json`, which can be efficiently implemented in standalone XQuery | SJS API  or interposed as XSLT `import-module`, is another helper to navigate between XML and JSON.  2) `flatNode` can be called into `flattenJson`.
> In this chain, I try to keep the XSL dialect as close to yours as possible.

> In reality, I just need slight XPath adjustments without touching the base templates `flattenJson` and `flatNode` to harmonise complex JSON.

Comment: `<xsl:if test="exists(others)"><otherPosition><xsl:for-each select="/others"><xsl:call-template name="flattenJson"/></xsl:for-each></otherPosition></xsl:if>`

Comment: Thank you, Fiona! It solved the `player` array issue. When I use similar logic to transform `others`, it didn’t transform the JSON to the expected XML. Can you point out what goes wrong? And does that XSLT3 actually transform JSON?

Comment: @Chris: please see the revised. If front-end load XSLT 3, it should be fine. If back-end load XSLT 3 into MarkLogic, I don’t feel it remotely synchronic.

Comment: Ms. Fiona: The updated Xsl transforms the JSON to the expected results!!

Comment: In the original XSLT, a simple adjustment to the XPath to select the `text()` nodes that are descendants of `player` would work wither a single value or values in an `array-node()`: `<xsl:for-each select="player//text()">`

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3.0 has the ability to process JSON: earlier versions do not. You don't appear to be making use of the XSLT 3.0 capabilities for handling JSON.

(You've tagged it "marklogic" - perhaps there is something in the ML XSLT processor that would make this work; I wouldn't know about that).

I would expect your code simply to fail saying that the input isn't well-formed XML.

Comment: No. The inputs are all valid. And I don't see how the XSLT 3 can do the work. Please show your solution.

Comment: MarkLogic can apply an XSLT transform to JSON documents. There are currently a few issues, but it is possible. The capability predated the newer XSLT 3.0 features for JSON support.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: can you show your MarkLogic xsl as the best effort? My question is to transform the most simple JSON to xml.

Comment: @Chris It seems you're relying on a feature of the Marklogic XSLT processor with which I was unfamiliar. Sorry, I don't have time to do a worked XSLT 3.0 solution for you.